# GHC Prefer one specialization over another

Tags: haskell, ghc

I have a Haskell typeclass function that looks like the following:

```
class Foo m where
   foo :: Num a => m a -> a
```

I want to generate two specializations of `foo`, one for anytime that `m ~ X Int` and the other when `m ~ X Int, a ~ Int`. I wrote the following code for this:

```
instance Foo (X a) where
   {-# SPECIALIZE instance Foo (X Int) #-}
   foo = ...
   {-# SPECIALIZE foo :: X Int Int -> Int #-}
```

From what I can tell, in the file that contains this code I am getting both specializations. However, in the module that is using `Foo` it seems to always point to the *less generic* specialization, i.e. `foo :: Num a => X Int a -> a` even when `a ~ Int`.

Is there a way to tell GHC to prefer the most specialized version of `foo` rather than the partially specialized version?

Thanks.

Comment: Possibly related to https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/13873 . It might be worth commenting there if you think your issue is related.